# Stylizing text within a div

Tags: html, css, text, text-styling

I am trying to stylize some text within a div. If you take a look at my livelink below you will see the square I need to add the stylized text to and also below is an image I created of how I would like the stylized text to loo.

[Here is the image I'm trying to duplicate using CSS and text](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/Untitled-1.jpg)

[Here is my Livelink](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/newpage.html)

Can somebody please show me how to achieve this?

***CSS***

```
.trigger {
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
.trigger.large {
width: 400px;
}
.trigger.vertical {
height: 400px;
}
.trigger.vertical * {
height: 400px;
}
.hover-img, .hover-img.hover_effect {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #CCCCB2;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.trigger.large .hover-img, .trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
width: 400px;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);
-o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
transform: rotateY(360deg);
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFF;
}
.img1 {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img1:hover {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img2 {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img2:hover {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img3 {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img3:hover {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img4 {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img4:hover {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img5 {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 
.img5:hover {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img6 {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img6:hover {
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#container {
width:960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
display: flex;
}
.col {
display:inline-block;
}
.trigger.large .hover-img, .trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
width: 400px;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="trigger vertical">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img3"><span  class="step">Step</span> <span class="number">1</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- </div>
 <div  class="row">-->
    <div class="col">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger large">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="trigger">
<div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img1"> </div>
</div>
<div class="trigger">
<div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img2"> </div>
</div>
<div class="trigger">
<div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img3"></div>
</div>
<div class="trigger">
<div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your link to the image goes to a 404 error

Comment: @DavidP My apologies this is now fixed

Comment: @steviepeters What font family is that in the picture? Figure that out and apply it to your CSS. You could see if you can find something similar at [google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I was thinking more about the positioning etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an unusual font you should probably stick to using an image. If a user doesn't have the font you specify in CSS its going to default to something that is ugly. YES - you can embed the font into CSS by using @font-face in CSS3. But you are going to have to limit your site to CSS3 compliant browsers, and only use TTF/OTF and WOFF fonts.

Comment: I have decided to use images instead